# How to union stored procedures into a temp table with column names and data types matching the schema from the stored procedure in SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema, create-table

I want to union the results from a stored procedure but it looks like to do this is to insert it into a newly created table.

The stored procedure outputs all the columns from an existing table so I would need to create a table with the same column names and data types.

```
CREATE TABLE #foo (bar int ...)

INSERT #foo
exec MyStoredProcedure 1

INSERT #foo
exec MyStoredProcedure 2

INSERT #foo
exec MyStoredProcedure 3
```

I'd need to list all column names and data types for table #foo.

Can this be done using information from the table's schema:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, 
    DATA_TYPE, 
    IS_NULLABLE, 
    CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, 
    NUMERIC_PRECISION, 
    NUMERIC_SCALE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='MyTable';
```

Where `MyTable` is the table which is output from the stored procedure.

Edit: this is using SQL Server

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL server. Sorry I'll put that in the question